# str_replace function not working as expected

Tags: php, string

I'm importing data into mysql using php from a csv. I want to replace empty date fields with a date captured in a variable. I thought I could use this but it's not working:

```
$appt_date=str_replace('', $alt_date, $appt_date);
```

Any ideas why this won't work?

Comment: Ternary it `$appt_date = !empty($appt_date) : $appt_date ? $alt_date;`.

Comment: Any errors/warning? What is the data it is not working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace()` is for replacing substrings within a string with something else, not for matching the whole string. You should use an `if` statement.

```
if ($appt_date == '') {
    $appt_date = $alt_date;
}
```

Comment: I have two columns i'm running this on, 1 is the above appt_date and the other is appt_time. The $appt_time = 'am'; and it works fine. The $appt_date = $alt_date; is passing back a different value, echo $alt_date; give the correct date - not sure whats wrong

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, this should work. You need to post your full code.